# Change buck adb port

Tags: buck

Is there a way to change the default port that buck uses for adb?

I have an adb tunneling on a server to use my local machine connected devices, so I'm using a different port that the default one (5037).

But when I do a buck install it spawns a new adb server using the default port, which of course won't find any device...

I tried to look a the documentation and code and I couldn't find any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since buck only calls the `adb` command, setting the `ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT` env variable should change the port that `adb` uses. Just make sure to kill any `buck` and `adb` process after setting the variable